# .NET MAUI 7 Android WebViewClient OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest override is never called

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

In my .NET MAUI App I' ve implemented a WebView with a url. When navigate to the website a simple js popup login come up. Now in my app i want to set credentials programmatically.

Im trying to handle js login request on webpage by overriding OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest method and pass username and password to the handler.Proceed but the method is never called.

My class:

```
public class BasicAuthWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    private readonly string Username;
    private readonly string Password;

    public BasicAuthWebViewClient(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm)
    {
        handler.Proceed(Username, Password);
    }
}
```

And the constructor:

```
androidWebView.SetWebViewClient(new BasicAuthWebViewClient(settings.Credentials.Username, settings.Credentials.Password));
```

Comment: Can you include the code (at a minimum the signature) of your method that's overriding the base?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now I resolved passing username and password to the url like this:

```
https://username:password@mywebsite.com/
```